# Time taken to krige in gstat package in R

Tags: r, kriging, gstat, geor

The following R program creates an interpolated surface using 470 data points using walker Lake data in gstat package.

```
source("D:/kriging/allfunctions.r")          # Reads in all functions.
source("D:/kriging/panel.gamma0.r")          # Reads in panel function for xyplot.
library(lattice)                          # Needed for "xyplot" function.
library(geoR)                             # Needed for "polygrid" function.
library(akima)  
library(gstat);
library(sp);
walk470 <- read.table("D:/kriging/walk470.txt",header=T)
attach(walk470)
coordinates(walk470) = ~x+y
walk.var1 <- variogram(v ~ x+y,data=walk470,width=10)  #the width has to be tuned resulting different point pairs
plot(walk.var1,xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",main="Variogram for V, Lag Spacing = 5")
model1.out <- fit.variogram(walk.var1,vgm(70000,"Sph",40,20000))
plot(walk.var1, model=model1.out,xlab="Distance",ylab="Semivariance",main="Variogram for V, Lag Spacing = 10")
poly <- chull(coordinates(walk470))
plot(coordinates(walk470),type="n",xlab="X",ylab="Y",cex.lab=1.6,main="Plot of Sample and Prediction Sites",cex.axis=1.5,cex.main=1.6)
lines(coordinates(walk470)[poly,])
poly.in <- polygrid(seq(2.5,247.5,5),seq(2.5,297.5,5),coordinates(walk470)[poly,])
points(poly.in)
points(coordinates(walk470),pch=16)
coordinates(poly.in) <- ~ x+y
krige.out <- krige(v ~ 1, walk470,poly.in, model=model1.out)
print(krige.out)
```

This program calculates the following for each point of 2688 points

```
(470x470) matrix inversion
(470x470) and (470x1) matrix multiplication
```

Is gstat package is using some smart way for calculation. I knew from previous stackoverflow query that it uses cholesky decomposition for matrix inversion. Is it normal speed for one machine to calculate it so quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses LDL' decomposition, which is similar to Choleski. As you are using global kriging, the covariance matrix needs to be decomposed only once; then, for each prediction point, a system is solved, which is O(n). No 470x470 matrix gets ever inverted, neither are solutions obtained by multiplying it. Inverses are notational devices, but avoided as computational strategy when possible. In R, for instance, compare runtime of `solve(A,b)` with `solve(A) %*% b`.

Use the [source](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/gls.c?view=markup&root=gstat), Luke!